# How Get RoleID in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, roles

Is there any way to get RoleId without get directly from DB?, I know we can get role Names by:

```
string[] allRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
string[] allRolesForUser = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```

But I need to access roleId.

Does any one have any idea about it?

Comment: The Role API doesn't provide a way to get role IDs. I suppose you could create a custom role provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The role provider have no knowledge about the data source. It can be a very slow web service or a super deluxe NoSQL database. The provider doesn't know that your db as a primary key.

Sure. The `SqlMembershipProvider` does. But having it exposing the key would likely lead to violations against [Liskovs Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428725/can-you-explain-liskov-substitution-principle-with-a-good-c-sharp-example).

The role name should be unique. So you should yourself be able to fetch it from the database. Or why can`t you simply use the role name directly instead of the db key?

Comment: ASP.NET Role Manager has a bug. Though doesn't allow duplicate role, if role has white space in-between and put different white-spaces for different roles, they are allowed, finally being multiple roles with same name !

Comment: the bug is that you allow white spaces.

Comment: but .NET should truncate multiple to single whitespace and validate !

Comment: why? It's your business rule, not the membership providers. Or is that rule listed anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: it's .NET validation that prevents duplicate roles, why not in that case ?

Comment: Because they are not duplicates. You have different characters in them.

Comment: then why .NET prevents duplicate role names, whereas I need to have different characters in them though with the same name.

Comment: I'll tell you why --- because the .NET role/user provider is a pile of junk. It's extremely limited in what it allows you to do. My advice, don't use it if you're looking for anything more than a bare-bones ability to create users and roles and associate them together.

Answer (score 2):

You must add aspnet_Roles table to your model and use query (for example LINQ) to get roleId .You can change MembershipProvider but it need more work for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. ASP.NET MVC doesn't allow to get RoleId with standard functon, you must get it from database with the help of role name.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a few years old, but when i bumped into it I saw that noone actually answers completely answers the question ...so I thought I would post a full solution.

Soooo...

Simply put:

```
SELECT RoleId, RoleName FROM aspnet_Roles;
GO
```

But for getting RoleIds for a User it is like this:

```
SELECT UR.RoleID, R.RoleName FROM
aspnet_Users U, aspnet_Roles R, aspnet_UsersInRoles UR 
WHERE U.UserName = @Username 
AND UR.UserId = U.UserId 
AND UR.RoleID = R.RoleId
GO
```

This will give you a 2 column list of RoleIds and RoleNames for a particular user.

In reality, you should not be trying to do this as there is a potential for Security breach when a RoleId is exposed. You should only work with RoleNames and use the Membership and Roles methods to manage things.

Hope this helps :)