# How can I call a non-static method out of another class in C#?

Tags: c#, class

The question itself sounds a bit nooby. To call a non static method from another class you have to use the current instance of the class. I tried to get the instance of the class with the method i want to call to the second class. I think I succeeded but it is still not working yet.

This one way how I tried to bring the instance to the second class:

```
arbeitsbearbeitung arbeitenbearbeitung = new arbeitsbearbeitung(arbeit);
arbeitenbearbeitung.Parent = this;
arbeitenbearbeitung.Show();
```

(out of Class 1)

And this is where I used it in class 2:

```
Form frm = (Form)this.Parent;
frm.updateGrid();
```

I also tried it with different ways like passing it as parameter; same result...

This is `updateGrid()` in class 1:

```
public void updateGrid()
{
    klassenarbeitenTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Klassenarbeiten);
}
```

It tells me that Form does not contain a definition for `updateGrid`.

I must be dumb but I can't find my mistake.

Thinking and googling for 2 hours and still no clue.

I feel dumb now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form` does not have an `updateGrid` method but your derived class does. You need to cast Parent to your class:
    MyForm frm = (MyForm)this.Parent;

Answer (score 2):

> you have to use the current instance of the class

You have to use **an** instance of the class. Not necessarily the current one.

> I tried to get the instance of the class

There is not **the** instance (unless it's a singleton), there is **an** instance.

Next, Microsoft has implemented `Form` as part of the .NET framework. Microsoft's `Form` class does not have a `updateGrid()` method.

If you created a form, then that form *inherits* from `Form` and you added the method `updateGrid()`. So instead of casting to `Form`, cast it to your class.

So the code might read

```
arbeitsbearbeitung frm = (arbeitsbearbeitung) this.Parent;
frm.updateGrid();
```

Note that this is not clean code, since it breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428725/can-you-explain-liskov-substitution-principle-with-a-good-c-sharp-example). But I think that's not your primary concern at the moment.

Comment: I think in my case I need the current instance of the class because I want the changes to be on the visible Form. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Milanisius: yes, if you have only one form open, then you should use that one, that is: it won't help if you just `new`'d up another instance. But in general (you were talking about classes, not Forms), you have access to many objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `frm` as a plain `Form`:

```
Form frm = (Form)this.Parent;
```

The problem is that the `Form` class has no function called `updateGrid`. When you say `frm.updateGrid()`, the compiler thinks "OK, `frm` is a `Form`, but `Form` doesn't have anything called `updateGrid`". It doesn't know that `frm` will actually be your special subclass of `Form` with the `updateGrid` function defined.

Instead, you need to declare `frm` with the actual class of Class 1:

```
MyCustomForm frm = (MyCustomForm)this.Parent;
```

Then when you do `frm.updateGrid()`, the compiler will know what you're talking about.