# How to change the generic type of a lambda function in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, casting, type-conversion

I am facing the following problem with conversion of the inner type in `Predicate<T>`. I have a class implementing a basic interface. Additionally to the interface, the class has some advanced properties and methods.

```cs
public interface IBasic { /* ... */ }
public class Advanced : IBasic { /* ... */ }
```

In a method I get a number of predicates over the `Advanced` class and I would like to sort them into two lists: 1) predicates that use only the `IBasic` interface 2) predicates that need all features from the `Advanced` class.

```
List<Predicate<IBasic>> basic = new List<Predicate<IBasic>>();
List<Predicate<Advanced>> advanced = new List<Predicate<Advanced>>();

public void SetPredicates(params Predicate<Advanced>[] predicates)
{
    foreach(var item in predicates)
    {
        //Of course the `is` keyword does not work here, always returning false.
        //Is it possible to do the check on the lambda function in item in a different way?
        if (item is Predicate<IBasic>)
            basic.Add((Predicate<IBasic>)item); //And this cast throws an exception of course.
        else
            advanced.Add(item);
    }
}
```

#### Questions

- Is it possible at all?
- How can I check if the generic type of the predicate can be reduced to the `IBasic` interface?
- How can I perform the predicate cast?

The number of predicates is low, so I am fine using slower things like reflection of `dynamic` types.

#### Background

The reason for the partition of predicates is that I have lots of `Advanced` instances. I want to pre-filter them first by predicates that require only the `IBasic` interface as those evaluate very fast. Then I will have to filter a much lower number of instances in the second pass with complex methods of `Advanced` (not in `IBasic`) since they take very long to evaluate.

Comment: This seems to completely break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428725/can-you-explain-liskov-substitution-principle-with-a-good-c-sharp-example). Sounds to me like something went wrong in the design, and now you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Have a look at [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thank you for the suggestion. I don't see how it would break it. Look on it a different way and if you find a better design, please let me know: I have the class `Advanced` with various properties. Some properties evaluate quick but some need really long. I have lots of `Advanced` instances to check, each needs to comply to a few predicates. I wish to pre-filter them using the fast predicates first. To identify which predicates are the *fast* ones, I extracted the *fast* properties to `IBasic` interface and now I am trying to do the type checking & casting.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you! Yes I am trying to do a contravariant generic cast at runtime. From what I understood from the article it could work if I had the cast right at the lambda body, e.g. `SetPredicates((IBasic b) => b.Count > 1 )` but I have no control how the method is called. I will try to break it into two methods just ot see if that helps despite being worse design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PavelAnikhouski pointed me to a right direction. The issue is that contravariance  [would be impractical for arrays](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/899319/Comparing-covariance-contravariance-rules). Nevertheless, it is possible to perform the contravariant cast at compile time **by omiting `params`**.

So instead of calling:

```cs
item.SetPredicates(x => !x.Empty /*IBasic*/, x => x.IsGlobalOptimum /*Advanced*/);
```

it can be broken into separate calls, each being correctly recognized by the compiler:

```cs
item.AddPredicate(x => !x.Empty); //IBasic
item.AddPredicate(x => x.IsGlobalOptimum); //Advanced
```

The `Advanced` class then has two overloaded methods:

```cs
public void AddPredicate(Predicate<IBasic> p)
{
    basic.Add(p);
}

public void AddPredicate(Predicate<Advanced> p)
{
    advanced.Add(p);
}
```

This is not the best interface, it would be nicer to be able to bulk add several predicates at once, but it works. In case anyone finds a more elegant solution, I will be glad to see and discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement an overloaded Constructor in the Predicate Class. One for Basic and the other for Advanced. Also do a bool check on the item to see it is a basic check?

also maybe you can do some sort of boolean check on some property of the item to see if it is basic

```
List<Predicate<IBasic>> basic = new List<Predicate<IBasic>>();
List<Predicate<Advanced>> advaned = new List<Predicate<Advanced>>();

public void SetPredicates(params Predicate<Advanced>[] predicates)
{
    foreach(var item in predicates)
    {
        //Of course the `is` keyword does not work here, always returning false.
        //Is it possible to do the check on the lambda function in item in a different way?
        if (item is Predicate<IBasic>)
            basic.Add(new Predicate(item, isBasic)); //And this cast throws an exception of course.
        else
            advanced.Add(new Predicate(item));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the `Predicate` class from the `System` assembly. It is sealed, no chance to overload a constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: you could try this 



`public void SetPredicates(params Predicate<Advanced>[] predicates)
{
    foreach(var item in predicates.FindAll( x => x is IBasic))
    {
            basic.Add(item); 
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but `x => x is IBasic` is wrong, it should be `x => x is Predicate<IBasic>` which is for the CLR just the same as my example in the answer.